# Windows Batch stdin and stdout in loop error

Tags: function, batch-file, for-loop, stdout, stdin

I'm a batch beginner. I would like to iterate through all files in some folder and successively pass them as input to *foo.exe*, at the same time I would like to pass the output to a file called *myOut.out*. I wrote the following code:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
    foo.exe < %1 > myOut.out
)
exit /b 0
```

It returns an error : `> was unexpected at this time.` For some reason when I do it in such a way, it works :

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
    call :run %%i
)
exit /b 0

:run
foo.exe < %1 > myOut.out
exit /b 0
```

Why is that? How can I do it properly?

Comment: In your first set of code: `foo.exe < %1 > myOut.out` should be `foo.exe < %%i > myOut.out`

Comment: Yeah right, copied incorrectly.

Comment: Try `foo.exe < "%%i" > myOut.out`. There may be some funny characters in one of the filenames and when it gets expanded it causes a problem with the parsing of the line.

Comment: Oh wait, it works now (%%i solved it). Stupid mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When debugging a batch file it helps to keep echo on and watch the code execute line by line. That way you can see the variables expand.